# an expression in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a question about the following statement in tcl

```
set hello [format %x [expr { 2**($D - 1)}]]
```

the proc takes $D as a parameter, I pass it as 1, but it complains  syntax error in expression " 2**($D - 1)": unexpected operator *

can anyone helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of Tcl do not have an exponentiation operator **. You will need to use the pow function.

```
set hello [format %x [expr {int(pow(2, $D - 1))}]]
```

Do note that `pow()` returns a floating-point value

Comment: I have never seen anyone brace the argument to expr. What sort of pattern would be valid for expr but produce unexpected results without braces?

Comment: @kostix what is the brace expr experisson you mean?

Comment: you should probably ask that as a new question!

Comment: but the short answer is it gives perf improvements and can prevent precision and security problems

Comment: A discussion on why you should brace the argument to `expr`: http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225

Comment: @Kurt: Anything with the `? :`, `&&` or `||` operators, especially if they involve a side-effect-ful call to a command somewhere that's guarded. Also, if the result of the command (or a variable read) is not a number, you can get excitement. Ask it as a proper question and I'll go into more depth.